# Another terms or word to describe 'someone who always support you in your fight in life'

Tags: single-word-requests

What is another term (preferably close to younger female), to describe 'someone who always support you in your fight in life'.

Closest term I have is: Sidekick.

Comment: Why doesn't "sidekick" work?

Comment: I changed the tag from "word-choice" (since you weren't offering a selection to choose from) to "single-word-requests" (since that seemed to fit your question). Note, however, that [such questions need a sample sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). (Feel free to use another tag, such as "phrase-requests", if you're actually looking for something else.)

Comment: What's wrong with "friend", "best friend", "BFF" or similar terms? And what do you mean "fight in life"? Are you talking about someone who accompanies you in everyday struggles, or something more like an actual superhero and sidekick?

Comment: Absent context, this question will become a series of guesses and opinions and thus should be closed.

Comment: Your *exponent* would be the one who supports, promotes and champions your cause?

Answer (score 0):

**Cheerleader**

A term that could describe someone who consistently supports you in your life's battles, particularly if you're looking for a term related to a younger female, is a "cheerleader." In this context, a "cheerleader" refers to someone who offers encouragement, motivation, and support to help you overcome challenges and achieve your goals. It conveys the idea of someone who stands by your side, uplifts you, and cheers you on in your pursuits.

> A person who leads spectators in cheering, usually a member of a team that performs dance, acrobatic, and tumbling routines at sporting events or in competitions with other teams.

> A person who encourages and openly supports the success of a person or cause:
> Her dad has always been her biggest cheerleader.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cheerleader)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***helpmate***

> one who is a companion and helper
> especially : WIFE ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/helpmate))